# how to read "nth" in English

Tags: pronunciation

I came across a statement **Return "nth" from the last node**
And I realized I don't know how to say "nth"
How to read it? Don't tell me N-T-H please!

Comment: There are dictionaries that give the pronunciation of this word; e.g. you can listen to it or see it transcribed here: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nth

Comment: The two most common pronunciations in U.S. English of "nth" in the expression "to the nth degree," I believe, are "inth" and "enth"; the preference in pronunciation (as with "pin" and "pen" for the word _pen_) depends largely on the part of the country where the speaker grew up.

Comment: @SvenYargs: the correct pronunciation is *enth*. It's just that some people happen to pronounce *enth* the same as *inth.*

Answer (score 3):

The letters of the alphabet all have names so the alphabet could be written as a, bee,cee and so on, and the letter 'n' has the name 'en' so the pronunciation of 'nth' is 'enth'.

This is somewhat analagous to talking about the position of 'm' in the alphabet. There are twelve letters before 'm' so its position is 13 which can also be written as 'thirteen'. It is therefore the 13th letter of the alpabet which can also be written as the thirteenth. In the first case we are using the symbol, in the second the name.

The parallel is that when we write about a letter we can either use its symbol or its name. It is perfectly acceptable to write either "There is a silent k in knowledge' or 'There is a silent kay in knowledge' but both sentences are pronounced in the same way.